# In yED Graph Editor, How to quickly replace straight arrows to bezier curve arrows?

Tags: flowchart, graph-visualization

I have a graph that is interconnected with directed straight edges. How to quickly replace them into bezier curve or orthogonal edges? Is it supported?

Like in the following example: (I did it manually, but I'd like to know if it can be done fully automaticly)

[image]

is transformed to =>

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do that:

- Select a single edge by clicking it
- Hit Ctrl-A to select all edges
- Find the type of edge in the palette
- Use the context menu "Apply" or "Apply Type" (if you want to keep color and other properties.

If by "fully automatically" you mean a programmatic way where no interaction in the UI is required, then you should be looking at [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/yfilesjava).